# Android Studio is changing my API level from 23 to 26

Tags: android

Thanks for stopping by. I have been working on an app at API 23.  Now Android Studio is "upgrading" it to API 26.  This is not what I want.  I want to keep it at API 23. Everytime I make a new app its 26.  Downgrading doesn't work; I get a bunch of errors.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change it as you like.

1.Click on your project folder > app > build.gradle
An example of build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.stackoverflow.answer"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}

dependencies {
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

2.Open your Android Studio, and go to Menu.

- File >Project Structure. In project Structure window, select app module in the list given on left side.
- Select the Flavors tab and under this you will have an option for setting “Min Sdk Version” and for setting “Target Sdk Version”.
- Select both the versions and Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if you're uploading it to the play store, it's going to have to target 26, soon to be 27. That's probably why AS is trying to update your version.